# How do I parse my string array to my c# model?

Tags: c#, ajax, json

This is my c# code:

```
  public void addBoxScore(string[] playerstats) 
    {
       Games gamestats = new Games();

       gamestats.GAME_ID = Int32.Parse(playerstats[0]);
       gamestats.TEAM_ID = Int32.Parse(playerstats[1]);
       gamestats.TEAM_ABBREVIATION = playerstats[2];
       gamestats.TEAM_CITY = playerstats[3];
       gamestats.PLAYER_ID = Int32.Parse(playerstats[4]);
       gamestats.PLAYER_NAME = playerstats[5];
       gamestats.START_POSITION = playerstats[6];
       gamestats.COMMENT = playerstats[7];

       gamestats.MIN = Int32.Parse(playerstats[8]);
       gamestats.FGM = Int32.Parse(playerstats[9]);
       gamestats.FGA = Int32.Parse(playerstats[10]);
       gamestats.FG_PCT = Int32.Parse(playerstats[11]);
       gamestats.FGTHREEM = Int32.Parse(playerstats[12]);
       gamestats.FGTHREEA = Int32.Parse(playerstats[13]);
       gamestats.FGTHREE_PCT = Int32.Parse(playerstats[14]);
       gamestats.FTM = Int32.Parse(playerstats[15]);
       gamestats.FTA = Int32.Parse(playerstats[16]);
       gamestats.FT_PCT = Int32.Parse(playerstats[17]);
       gamestats.OREB = Int32.Parse(playerstats[18]);
       gamestats.DREB = Int32.Parse(playerstats[19]);
       gamestats.REB = Int32.Parse(playerstats[20]);
       gamestats.AST = Int32.Parse(playerstats[21]);
       gamestats.STL = Int32.Parse(playerstats[22]);
       gamestats.BLK = Int32.Parse(playerstats[23]);
       gamestats.TO = Int32.Parse(playerstats[24]);
       gamestats.PF = Int32.Parse(playerstats[25]);
       gamestats.PTS = Int32.Parse(playerstats[26]);
       gamestats.PLUS_MINUS = Int32.Parse(playerstats[27]);


    }
```

and this is my javascript that gets the data from the api and sends it to the controller.

```
  var date = "05/05/2014";

$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: "post",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboard/?LeagueID=00&gameDate=' + date + '&DayOffset=0',
    success: function (val) {
        var result = val.resultSets[0].rowSet;
        $.each(result, function (key, value) {
            var gameID = this[2];
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "jsonp",
                async: false,
                type: "post",
                crossDomain: true,
                gameID: { gameID: gameID },
                url: "http://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscore?GameID=" + gameID + "&RangeType=0&StartPeriod=0&EndPeriod=0&StartRange=0&EndRange=0",
                success: function (gameinfo) {
                    var w = gameinfo.resultSets[0].rowSet[0];
                    if (w[4] == "Final") {
                        var pstats = gameinfo.resultSets[4].rowSet;
                        $.each(pstats, function (key, value) {
                            var playerstats = this;
                            $.ajax({
                                async: false,
                                type: "post",
                                url: "/Stats/addBoxScore",
                                data: { playerstats: JSON.stringify(playerstats) },
                                done: function (data) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                },
                                error: function (jqXHR, err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                }
                            });

                        });
                    };   
                }
```

And this is what the data that the controller recieves looks like:

```
"[\"0041300201\",1610612764,\"WAS\",\"Washington\",2772,\"Trevor Ariza\",\"F\",\"\",\"37:20\",7,10,0.7,6,6,1,2,4,0.5,1,5,6,2,1,0,0,3,22,18]"
```

This is my model:

```
   public class Games
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int GAME_ID { get; set; }
    public int TEAM_ID { get; set; }
    public string TEAM_ABBREVIATION { get; set; }
    public string TEAM_CITY { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int PLAYER_ID { get; set; }
    public string PLAYER_NAME { get; set; }
    public string START_POSITION { get; set; }
    public string COMMENT { get; set; }
    public int MIN { get; set; }
    public int FGM { get; set; }
    public int FGA { get; set; }
    public int FG_PCT { get; set; }
    public int FGTHREEM { get; set; }
    public int FGTHREEA { get; set; }
    public int FGTHREE_PCT { get; set; }
    public int FTM { get; set; }
    public int FTA { get; set; }
    public int FT_PCT { get; set; }
    public int OREB { get; set; }
    public int DREB { get; set; }
    public int REB { get; set; }
    public int AST { get; set; }
    public int STL { get; set; }
    public int BLK { get; set; }
    public int TO { get; set; }
    public int PF { get; set; }
    public int PTS { get; set; }
    public int PLUS_MINUS { get; set; }

    public virtual Player player { get; set; } 
}
```

Why does it put \ in every string in the array? And how do i parse it to my model?

Comment: Did you try [Json.Decode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Web.Helpers.Json%29;k%28SolutionItemsProject%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) to deserialize you data?

Comment: @DmytroTsiniavskyi no i haven't! Should it be in my c# code?

Comment: Did you copy paste that from the debugger? Because it displays string data as literal (that is, special characters escaped) – so "\"" is actually "

Comment: Yes, I would also recommend you to create JSON objects and to deserialize it using the JSON serialization methods in C#

Comment: Yes @marsze i copied it from the debugger.

Comment: @Rafa can you give me an example on how to do that?

Comment: in your javascript:

JSON.stringify()

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: And in your C# code, you will find an example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should help.

```
using System.Web.Helpers;    

public void addBoxScore(string playerstats) 
{
    Games gamestats = Json.Decode<Games>(playerstats);
}
```

**Edits**
Well, I'm not sure that fully understand the structure of your model, but... Try the following:

```
public void addBoxScore(string playerstats) 
{
    var gamestats = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode<IEnumerable<Games>>(playerstats);
}
```

**More Edits**
Now I can spot the problem. `Json.Decode()` will not help you to create your `Games` object because data you send to controller is just stringnified array of strings and property names, which are required for converting are not provided. Maximum what you can do - deserialize this string to proper C# string array manually, and then do what you have already done - assign each property one by one. You can refactor it to look more pretty, create some extension method for string or even use reflection to loop through `Games` properties for assignment ... For example:

```
public static class Extensions
    {
        public static Games ToGames(this string data)
        {
            var playerstats = data
                .Replace("[", string.Empty)
                .Replace("]", string.Empty)
                .Replace(@"\", string.Empty)
                .Replace("\"", string.Empty)
                .Split(',')
                .Select(s => s.Trim())
                .ToArray();


            var gamestats = new Games
            {
                GAME_ID = Int32.Parse(playerstats[0]),
                TEAM_ID = Int32.Parse(playerstats[1]),
                TEAM_ABBREVIATION = playerstats[2],
                TEAM_CITY = playerstats[3],
                PLAYER_ID = Int32.Parse(playerstats[4]),
                PLAYER_NAME = playerstats[5],
                START_POSITION = playerstats[6],
                COMMENT = playerstats[7],
                MIN = Int32.Parse(playerstats[8]),
                FGM = Int32.Parse(playerstats[9]),
                FGA = Int32.Parse(playerstats[10]),
                FG_PCT = Int32.Parse(playerstats[11]),
                FGTHREEM = Int32.Parse(playerstats[12]),
                FGTHREEA = Int32.Parse(playerstats[13]),
                FGTHREE_PCT = Int32.Parse(playerstats[14]),
                FTM = Int32.Parse(playerstats[15]),
                FTA = Int32.Parse(playerstats[16]),
                FT_PCT = Int32.Parse(playerstats[17]),
                OREB = Int32.Parse(playerstats[18]),
                DREB = Int32.Parse(playerstats[19]),
                REB = Int32.Parse(playerstats[20]),
                AST = Int32.Parse(playerstats[21]),
                STL = Int32.Parse(playerstats[22]),
                BLK = Int32.Parse(playerstats[23]),
                TO = Int32.Parse(playerstats[24]),
                PF = Int32.Parse(playerstats[25]),
                PTS = Int32.Parse(playerstats[26]),
                PLUS_MINUS = Int32.Parse(playerstats[27])
            };

            return gamestats;
        }
    }
```

And then in your controller:

```
public void addBoxScore(string playerstats)
{
     Games result = playerstats.ToGames();
}
```

Also I have a question - What is `MIN = Int32.Parse(playerstats[8])`? Because it has a value of `37:20` (in example string you provided) and I'm not sure I understand what is this, because it will give the error during conversion to int.

Comment: i get this error: system.web.controller.json(object) is a method which is not valid in the given context

Comment: @DanielGustafsson, I suggest you forgot to add necessary namespace: `System.Web.Helpers`

Comment: @DanielGustafsson, Have you tried to use namespace directly? `Games gamestats = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode<Games>(playerstats);` ?

Comment: That worked better! But now when i run it i get this error: SportsFantasy.Models.Games is not supported for deserialization of an array

Comment: @DanielGustafsson - try var stats = Json.Decode<string[]>(playerstats);

Comment: now we are back to the same error: Error 1 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Json(object)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SportsFantasy\SportsFantasy\Controllers\StatsController.cs 30 31 SportsFantasy

Comment: i added my model to the question. This is the error i get when using your edit code: cannot convert object of type system.string to type sports fantasy.model.games

Comment: @DanielGustafsson, Can you show how does `playerstats` data looks like before you call `JSON.stringify(playerstats)`? I mean what does api return?

Comment: @DanielGustafsson, also if nothing helps you can remove \ using `result.Replace(@"\", string.Empty);` and do what you have done before just to make it work...

Comment: If i debugg it in chrome ill get this value before it i hits the stringify: 

["0041300201", 1610612764, "WAS", "Washington", 2772, "Trevor Ariza", "F", "", "37:20", 7, 10, 0.7, 6, 6, 1, 2, 4, 0.5, 1, 5, 6, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 22, 18]

Comment: The replace thing doesn't realy work, like somebody mention in a comment to my question it isn't realy \ because it is character escaped and is rather -

Comment: It's the amount of minutes a player have played. But ive changed everything in the model to string and now it works perfectly!:) Thank you so mutch!!

Comment: @DanielGustafsson, if it is the amount of minutes - minutes:seconds - you should convert to [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd992370(v=vs.110).aspx) - `MIN = TimeSpan.ParseExact(playerstats[8], "mm\\:ss",                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` or to double...